# Troubleshooting: live chat implementation with react, node.js, and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have this ChatBox.js as component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';

const ENDPOINT =
  window.location.host.indexOf('localhost') >= 0
    ? 'http://127.0.0.1:4000'
    : window.location.host;

export default function ChatBox(props) {
  const { userInfo } = props;
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
  const uiMessagesRef = useRef(null);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [messageBody, setMessageBody] = useState('');
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([
    { name: 'Admin', body: 'Hello there, Please ask your question.' },
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (uiMessagesRef.current) {
      uiMessagesRef.current.scrollBy({
        top: uiMessagesRef.current.clientHeight,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    }

    if (socket) {
      socket.emit('onLogin', {
        _id: userInfo._id,
        name: userInfo.name,
        isAdmin: userInfo.isAdmin,
      });
      socket.on('message', (data) => {
        setMessages([...messages, { body: data.body, name: data.name }]);
      });
    }
  }, [socket]);

  const supportHandler = () => {
    console.log(ENDPOINT);
    const sk = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
    setSocket(sk);
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!messageBody.trim()) {
      alert('Error. Please type message.');
    } else {
      const newMessageBody = messageBody; // Salvăm valoarea actualizată într-o nouă variabilă
      setMessages([...messages, { body: newMessageBody, name: userInfo.name }]);
      setMessageBody('');
      setTimeout(() => {
        socket.emit('onMessage', {
          body: newMessageBody, // Utilizăm noua variabilă aici
          name: userInfo.name,
          isAdmin: userInfo.isAdmin,
          _id: userInfo._id,
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
  };

  const closeHandler = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="chatbox">
      {!isOpen ? (
        <button type="button" onClick={supportHandler}>
          <i className="fa fa-support" />
        </button>
      ) : (
        <div className="card card-body">
          <div className="row">
            <strong>Support </strong>
            <button type="button" onClick={closeHandler}>
              <i className="fa fa-close" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <ul ref={uiMessagesRef}>
            {messages.map((msg, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                <strong>{`${msg.name}: `}</strong> {msg.body}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          <div>
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler} className="row">
              <input
                value={messageBody}
                onChange={(e) => setMessageBody(e.target.value)}
                type="text"
                placeholder="type message"
              />
              <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have server.js like this:

```
import http from 'http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import seedRouter from './routes/seedRoutes.js';
import productRouter from './routes/productRoutes.js';
import userRouter from './routes/userRoutes.js';
import orderRouter from './routes/orderRoutes.js';
import uploadRouter from './routes/uploadRoutes.js';

dotenv.config();

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('connected to db');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/api/keys/paypal', (req, res) => {
  res.send(process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID || 'sb');
});
app.get('/api/keys/google', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ key: process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY || '' });
});

app.use('/api/upload', uploadRouter);
app.use('/api/seed', seedRouter);
app.use('/api/products', productRouter);
app.use('/api/users', userRouter);
app.use('/api/orders', orderRouter);

const __dirname = path.resolve();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/build')));
app.get('*', (req, res) =>
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/build/index.html'))
);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const httpServer = http.Server(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, { cors: { origin: '*' } });
const users = [];

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('connection', socket.id);
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    const user = users.find((x) => x.socketId === socket.id);
    if (user) {
      user.online = false;
      console.log('Offline', user.name);
      const admin = users.find((x) => x.isAdmin && x.online);
      if (admin) {
        io.to(admin.socketId).emit('updateUser', user);
      }
    }
    socket.emit('listUsers', users);
  });

  socket.on('onLogin', (user) => {
    const updatedUser = {
      ...user,
      online: true,
      socketId: socket.id,
      messages: [],
    };
    const existUser = users.find((x) => x._id === updatedUser._id);
    if (existUser) {
      existUser.socketId = socket.id;
      existUser.online = true;
      console.log('Existing User:', existUser);
    } else {
      users.push(updatedUser);
      console.log('New User:', updatedUser);
    }
    console.log('Online', user.name);
    const admin = users.find((x) => x.isAdmin && x.online);
    if (admin) {
      io.to(admin.socketId).emit('updateUser', updatedUser);
    }
    if (updatedUser.isAdmin) {
      io.to(updatedUser.socketId).emit('listUsers', users);
      console.log('List Users:', users);
    }
  });

  socket.on('onUserSelected', (user) => {
    const admin = users.find((x) => x.isAdmin && x.online);
    if (admin) {
      const existUser = users.find((x) => x._id === user._id);
      io.to(admin.socketId).emit('selectUser', existUser);
    }
  });

  socket.on('onMessage', (message) => {
    if (message.isAdmin) {
      const user = users.find((x) => x._id === message._id && x.online);
      if (user) {
        io.to(user.socketId).emit('message', message);
        user.messages.push(message);
      }
    } else {
      const admin = users.find((x) => x.isAdmin && x.online);
      if (admin) {
        io.to(admin.socketId).emit('message', message);
        const user = users.find((x) => x._id === message._id && x.online);
        user.messages.push(message);
      } else {
        io.to(socket.id).emit('message', {
          name: 'Admin',
          body: 'Sorry. I am not online right now',
        });
      }
    }
  });
});

httpServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Serve at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
// app.listen(port, () => {
//   console.log(`serve at http://localhost:${port}`);
// });
```

and i have chatScreen.js like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';

const ENDPOINT =
  window.location.host.indexOf('localhost') >= 0
    ? 'http://127.0.0.1:4000'
    : window.location.host;

export default function ChatScreen() {
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState({});
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
  const uiMessagesRef = useRef(null);
  const [messageBody, setMessageBody] = useState('');
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  if (uiMessagesRef.current) {
    uiMessagesRef.current.scrollBy({
      top: uiMessagesRef.current.clientHeight,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!socket) {
      const sk = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
      setSocket(sk);
      sk.emit('onLogin', { name: 'User' });

      sk.on('message', (data) => {
        if (selectedUser._id === data._id) {
          setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, data]);
        } else {
          setUsers((prevUsers) =>
            prevUsers.map((user) =>
              user._id === data._id ? { ...user, unread: true } : user
            )
          );
        }
      });

      sk.on('updateUser', (updatedUser) => {
        setUsers(
          (prevUsers) => {
            const existUser = prevUsers.find(
              (user) => user._id === updatedUser._id
            );
            if (existUser) {
              return prevUsers.map((user) =>
                user._id === existUser._id ? updatedUser : user
              );
            } else {
              return [...prevUsers, updatedUser];
            }
          },
          () => {
            console.log('Updated Users:', users);
          }
        );
      });
      sk.on('listUsers', (updatedUsers) => {
        setUsers(updatedUsers, () => {
          console.log('Updated Users:', users);
        });
      });
      sk.on('selectUser', (user) => {
        setMessages(user.messages);
      });
    }
  }, [selectedUser, socket]);

  const selectUser = (user) => {
    setSelectedUser(user);
    console.log('Selected User:', user);
    setUsers((prevUsers) =>
      prevUsers.map((x) => (x._id === user._id ? { ...x, unread: false } : x))
    );
    socket.emit('onUserSelected', user);
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!messageBody.trim()) {
      alert('Error. Please type a message.');
    } else {
      setMessages((prevMessages) => [
        ...prevMessages,
        { body: messageBody, name: 'User' },
      ]);
      console.log('Updated Messages:', messages); // Verificare lista de mesaje actualizată
      setMessageBody('');
      setTimeout(() => {
        socket.emit('onMessage', {
          body: messageBody,
          name: 'User',
          _id: selectedUser._id,
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="row top full-container">
      <div className="col-1 support-users">
        {users.length === 0 && (
          <MessageBox>
            No Online User Found {console.log('Users:', users)}
          </MessageBox>
        )}
        <ul>
          {users.map((user) => (
            <li
              key={user._id}
              className={user._id === selectedUser._id ? 'selected' : ''}
            >
              <button
                className="block"
                type="button"
                onClick={() => selectUser(user)}
              >
                {user.name}
              </button>
              <span
                className={
                  user.unread ? 'unread' : user.online ? 'online' : 'offline'
                }
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="col-3 support-messages">
        {!selectedUser._id ? (
          <MessageBox>Select a user to start chat</MessageBox>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <div className="row">
              <strong>Chat with {selectedUser.name} </strong>
            </div>
            <ul ref={uiMessagesRef}>
              {messages.length === 0 && <li>No messages.</li>}
              {messages.map((msg, index) => (
                <li key={index}>
                  <strong>{`${msg.name}: `}</strong> {msg.body}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
            <div>
              <form onSubmit={submitHandler} className="row">
                <input
                  value={messageBody}
                  onChange={(e) => setMessageBody(e.target.value)}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Type a message"
                />
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

in the console log from the connection made in server.js, Online User appears
Existing User: {
name: 'User',
online: true,
socketId: 'K0q9I-BoFIRN6IUEBBBO',
messages: []
}
Online User

but it appears on the application screen: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNks7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfOxi.png)

how could i fix this problem? where am I wrong?

I want to create a chat between admin and user using soket.io, but the data is not transmitted correctly.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code or errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417). Thank you